# Mongoose - get documents with best score but only one of each user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So this is how my mongoose schema looks like:

```
const QuizModel = new mongoose.Schema({ 
  quizId: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },  
  userId: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },  
  result: { 
    score: { type: Number, required: true},
    time: { type: Number, required: true },   
  }, 
});
```

This is a quiz application so there are multiple documents with same `userId`.
I am trying to make a query to build leaderboard and I came up with this.

```
const topUsers = await QuizModel.find({})
      .sort({ "result.score": "desc", "result.time": "asc" })
      .limit(10);
```

Now because I want to show only top 10 users, I have added `.limit(10)`.
Now in these 10 documents, there is chance that all the 10 docs are of same user i.e. same `userId`.

How do I prevent this and still get 10 documents with all unique `userId`?
I don't want a single user to occupy all 10 slots in leaderboard.

**Example:**
**User1** has 5 docs with above schema with scores 100, 95, 92, 90, 60
**User2** has 5 docs with above schema with scores 95, 92, 90, 80, 60

Expected Output is:

```
[
  {
    quizId: "....", 
    userId: "user1",
    result: {
      score: 100,
      time: "some_time"
    }
  },
  {
    quizId: "....", 
    userId: "user2",
    result: {
      score: 95,
      time: "some_time"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) along with [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) in order to aggregate the scores per user, try:

```
const topUsers = await QuizModel.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$userId",
            score: { $max: "$result.score" }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { score: 1 }
    },
    {
        $limit: 10
    }
])
```

Comment: No, I don't want sum per user. I only want the doc with best score of the user. You answer returns `[ { _id: 'thatUserId', score: 236 } ]`

Comment: @Dharmaraj you can use $max instead in such case

Comment: Thanks for your help :) and sorry I am new to aggregation. It's working perfectly. If I add any other field in `$group`, then it will return the field form the doc which has that max score right ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj not necessarly, $group aggregates the data so you can return $first, $last, $avg etc. If you want more fields from that document then sort by score before $group and then use $first / $last to retrieve more fields

Comment: Alright thanks for that :) I'll rad more about `$` operators